# How to format time in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to build an application which should give out the local time from Vienna. I formatted the time with `time = DateFormat.jm().format()`, but now I get a time like `14:25 PM`. How can I delete the PM, because I don´t need it?
This is the code I tried:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void getTime() async {
    String time;

    Response response =
        await get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Vienna");
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    String datetime = data["datetime"];
    String offset = data["utc_offset"].substring(1, 3);
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
    time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    print(time);
  }
```

And this is the time I get:

```
I/flutter ( 9302): 12:43 PM
```

Comment: what is the dateTime you are getting also offset

Comment: datetime = I/flutter ( 9302): 2020-05-17T12:57:04.064849+02:00
offset = I/flutter ( 9302): 02

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the [Intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) then you can do that without too much work by simply provide a custom formatter.

For your use-case you need to use the formatter `HH:mm` wich represents hour and minutes only.

```
final date = DateTime.now();
final hourAndMinues = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);

print(hourAndMinutes); // 12:00
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show DateTime object in local time in h:m format than you can do following

```
var local = dateTime.toLocal();
var format = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(local); //or h:m for 12 hour format without am/pm
print(format);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace

This line

```
time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
```

With

```
time = DateFormat.Hm().format(now);   // Hm Indicate hour and minute
```